# libgdx: Adding Table to Stage causes Actors that aren't children of the Table to not render, despite not having overlapping coordinates

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

So, I have a Game Screen that I have set to 800x480, and at the top of that screen I'm trying to create a Table that contains some information.  I've set the table bounds to x = 0, y = 380, width = 800, height = 100, and when the screen renders, the table shows up at the top of the screen just like I want.  However, below that table, I want to render additional Actors that I've added to my stage.  Problem is, they aren't rendering.  If I comment out the line where I add the table to the stage, everything renders just fine - its only when I add the table that the issue occurs, even though the non-Table Actors don't overlap screen coordinates with the Table.  For the purpose of this question, I cut out all of the Actors other than the one called "Field", which is a game board with coordinates of x=0, y=0, width=500, height=300.

Why is the inclusion of the Table obfuscating the rendering of my other Actors?

Here's my code  (first GameScreen, then Field):

```
public GameScreen(MyGame game) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.game = game;
        log = "Starting game";
        plyscore = 0;
        oppscore = 0;
        stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(800,480));
        gameskin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
        gametable = new Table();
        background = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(AssetLoader.background));
        field = new Field();
        score = new Label(plyscore+" - "+oppscore, gameskin);
        logarea = new TextArea(log, gameskin);
        logarea.setPrefRows(3);
        logscroll = new ScrollPane(logarea, gameskin);
        logscroll.setForceScroll(false, true);
        logscroll.setFlickScroll(false);
        gametable.setBounds(0, 380, 800, 100);
        gametable.add(score).width(390);
        gametable.add(logscroll).width(390).row();  
        stage.addActor(gametable);
        stage.addActor(field);



    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.draw();

    }

public class Field extends Actor {

    public Field() {
        setBounds(getX(), getY(), AssetLoader.field.getRegionWidth(),
                AssetLoader.field.getRegionHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        batch.draw(AssetLoader.field,this.getX(),getY());
    }

}
```

Comment: It works after swapping the order of stage.addActor(gametable) & stage.addActor(field).  Don't know why, but it does.

Comment: Correction, it only seems to work because I had added another table for a certain game state.  When I switched out of that state, the issue recurred.  I think it was because that other table included an animation.  Very confused.  I noticed that if I hover my mouse over the gametable, the actor that isn't showing up will show up, but then disappear.

Comment: It has something to do with using ScrollPane.  If I get rid of that, and just add the TextArea to the Table without adding it to ScrollPane first, there's no issue (other than the fact that I don't have a ScrollPane :))